# Creating a two-dimensional object from a string of values

Tags: javascript, object

In JavaScript, how would I create a two-dimensional object from a string of values, in which the first value would be the name, the last is the content, and all other values in between are properties?

For example, I have a string `"capitals,Asia,China,Beijing"` and I want the code to split this string into four values and create an object `capitals["Asia","China"] = "Beijing";`.

How could I do that?

In a complete code piece that would look like this:

```
<script>
  Values = "capitals,Asia,China,Beijing";
  Values = Values.split(",");
  alert(capitals["Asia","China"]);
</script>
```

I want the alert box to show me the word `Beijing`.

How could I do that?

Comment: Is requirement for both `"Asian"` and `"China"` properties to have value set to `"Beijing"`? Or for single property `"Asian China"` to be set to `"Beijing"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not have two-dimensional arrays or objects that you can access using `array[index1, index2]` as in some other languages. To do this, you have to use nested objects/arrays, such as

```
capitals["Asian"]["China"]
```

To create these, you can do something like:

```js
function makeEntry(obj, str) {
  const parts = str.split(',');          // array of comma-delimited values
  const value = parts.pop();             // final value ("Beijing")
  const final = parts.pop();             // final property ("China")

  // Find nested property, creating empty object if not there.
  for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    const part = parts[i];
    if (!(parts in obj)) obj[part] = {};
    obj = obj[part];
  }
      
  // Set final value.
  obj[final] = value;
}

const data = {};
makeEntry(data, "capitals,Asian,China,Beijing");
console.log(data);
console.log(data.capitals["Asian"]["China"]);
```

This code will work even if there are more levels, such as `"capitals,Asia,East Asia,China,Beijing"`.

Note that there is no way to create a variable in JS given a name. Therefore, we provide an initial object, and build the nest structure within it.

#### Another approach

Another approach is to create a single-level object with keys such as `"capitals,Asian,China"`. That's easier to create, but might be more inconvenient to access. For example, there would be no easy way to find all the Asian capitals. Below, I'm using regexp to pick apart the input into the first part and the final value.

```js
function makeEntry(obj, str) {
  const [, key, value] = str.match(/(.*),([^,]+)$/);
  obj[key] = value;
}

const data = {};
makeEntry(data, "capitals,Asian,China,Beijing");
console.log(data);
console.log(data["capitals,Asian,China"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) to set the key of the `WeakMap` object to an object; `Array.prototype.shift()`, `Array.prototype.splice()`, `Array.prototype.pop()` to set the value of the `WeakMap` object instance.

```js
let Values = "capitals,Asian,China,Beijing";
Values = Values.split(",");
const capitals = {[Values.shift()]:Values.splice(0, 2)};
const wm = new WeakMap;
wm.set(capitals, Values.pop());
console.log(wm.get(capitals));
```

You can alternatively set the property of an object to the result of `JSON.stringify()` called on `Values.splice(1, 2)`

```js
let Values = "capitals,Asian,China,Beijing";
Values = Values.split(",");
const key = JSON.stringify(Values.splice(1, 2));
console.log(key);
const map = {[Values.shift()]:{[key]:Values.pop()}};
console.log(map.capitals[key]);
```